# Angular 4 subscribe of paramMap not working with children outlet

Tags: angular, routes

In our `Angular 4 App` we have DropDown with a list of contracts.

Once the user selects a contract we trigger a `router.navigate`, changing the url with the selected `contractId` and we make a `http request` with it.

Actually it's pretty simple:

`this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(...request with contractId...)`

This works fine with flat routes.

But on routes with children it's not working, for example for this route:

```
export const customerRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: ":contractId/Customers",
    component: CustomersComponent,
    children: [
        { path: "", redirectTo: "Children", pathMatch: "full" },
        { path: "Children", component: ChildrenComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

The route above gives me the following URL: 
`http://localhost:4033/20917/Customers/Children`

Now let's assume I want to select in DropDown a new contract...

...that is the `onChange` of the DropDown:

```
public onChange(contract: Contract): void {
  this.router.navigate([contract.id, window.location.pathname.split("/")[3]]);
}
```

Where `window.location.pathname.split("/")[3]` gives me: **Customers**

The url changed to `http://localhost:4033/33444/Customers/Children`, BUT the subscribe has not been hit. Why?

Comment: Where is this code: `this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(...request with contractId...)`? It will only pick up changes to the routes associated with the component. So to pick up the `Children` route changes this code would need to be in the `Children` component. Is that were it is?

Comment: Thanks @DeborahK - yes that is exactly where is it - the subscriber is in the children component. It should be easy to reproduce this with a plunker. I'll give it a try...

Comment: I could fix the issue @DeborahK and it's pretty interesting. I haven't seen much about this on the web. I also tried the pluralsight courses and this was not covered there. When you are in a child component and wants to access a parameter of a parent component via subscription it's neede to use: `this.activatedRoute.parent.paramMap...` then it works. I'll poszt an answer with a link to a plunker

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I did discuss the .parent property of the activated route in my `Angular Routing` course on Pluralsight, but with regard to watching the data property. It's conceptually similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To watch for change events of a parent component, we need explicitly call:

`this.activatedRoute.parent.paramMap.subscribe(...request with contractId...)`

This is not in the docs and I already create a request for this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18862

Comment: looks like you closed the issue.. my I ask why? I have a similar problem now but have not found a solution still..

Comment: It was a request for a documentation and feature, not an issue. the solution is given above

Comment: @DAG Could you show how to do this with the pipe() operator? You can't use .map anymore since angular 6. I tried recreating what you made in plunkr like so: `                this.activatedRoute.parent.paramMap.pipe(
                      map(m => m.get("contractId")),
                      distinctUntilChanged((previous: any, current: any) => {return true})).subscribe(),` But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

For me neither `activatedRoute.parent.parentMap` nor `activatedRoute.parentMap` works. After some trials and errors I came up with following solution:

```
const params$ = router.events
    .pipe(map(() => _.assign({}, activatedRoute.snapshot.params, activatedRoute.firstChild?.snapshot.params)));
```

This finally shows me all parameters. It obviously should be debounced, because router emits a lot of events, but this is the best I could find.

I am using Angular 11.